# Transparent navigation soft buttons

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to find the xml theme parameter to make the soft navigation buttons e.g. in Nexus 5 on a given color/transparent and accept overlay. I cannot find something so far.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743124/setting-transparency-to-buttons-in-android), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643999/button-opacity-transparency), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954102/button-background-as-transparent) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383780/how-to-create-a-transparent-button)

Comment: @Outofmemory how do those exactly solve the problem? I am talking about the **system navigation soft buttons** (bottom of the picture). Not buttons in general.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. I am not sure of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that inside of an App I used this into styles.xml

`<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
 <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>`

But, you have to manage layout objects under navigation bar (like FAB Button).

Not sure if that is what you want, just give a try.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel. I had found the answer some time ago but nice that you replied! 